# If Android is a Linux distribution can I run it natively on my computer?

Tags: boot, linux, operating-system

Is it possible to run Android on PC?
Is it?

Comment: I wonder why this question is down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Despite that it's [worth discussing whether Android can be called a Linux distribution or not](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-linux-784964/), you can find several working Androids for desktop platforms:

- Android x86: http://www.android-x86.org/
- Remix OS ([discontinued](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/07/17/jide-technology-shifting-away-consumer-market-remix-os-discontinued/)): http://www.jide.com/remixos
- Bluestacks (virtual machine): http://www.bluestacks.com

Comment: Im talking about native Android vannila, no modifactions just android itself

Comment: And I think Android is most "linuxish" than Fedora or Arch  because it only uses Linux kernel itself, no GNU/X11 etc

Comment: Android **does not** use the standard Linux kernel. See the linked article.

Comment: Its still Linux kernel

Answer (score 0):

i would have to say yes as i have a linux android distro i have played with a few time i made a live bootable usb stick with lili i am not sure where i origanelly downloaded the ISO but i have had it boot fine a few times and also after some playing in the shell when it has not loaded properly other times not sure if its something from the creation of the usb or the different computers i have used it on. sorry i cant help more then that (is there a reason you cant just run knox to emulate)